# ¿Cómo obtener datos de segunda tabla de una colección?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo dos tablas con relación uno a muchos y necesito que al momento de hacer la función "index", me devuelva una colección que incluya los datos de la segunda tabla.
Me explico: Actualmente tengo la tabla "A" y la tabla "B", la tabla B tiene una fk de la tabla A.

Mis relaciones de modelos: 
1.-

```
public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'departamento');
    }
```

2.-

```
public function academics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Academic::class);
    }
```

En mi controlador tengo:

```
 public function index()
    {
         $academicos = Academic::all();

         return response()->json($academicos);
    }
```

y me imprime:

```
[{
  pk: bla,
  nombre: bla,
  departamento: 1  ->fk
}]
```

Pero yo quiero que me imprima algo como:

```
[{
  "pk": bla,
  "nombre": bla,
  "departamento": 1, 
  department":{      -->segunda tabla
    "pk": 1,
    "nombre": bla,
}]
```

Agradecería ayuda, espero que se haya entendido algo. 
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carga la relación como una propiedad mágica, gracias a Eloquent, y utiliza el método `get`:

```
Academic::with('department')->get();
```

Si deseas que SIEMPRE cargue dicha relación (o segunda tabla, como tú lo llamas) al momento de llamar un modelo de Academic, entonces agrega la siguiente propiedad al modelo `Academic`:

```
protected $with = ['department'];
```

Comment: Ha funcionado justo como lo necesitaba, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la función de eloquent llamada with()

Ello implica que debes cambiar:

```
public function index()
{
     $academicos = Academic::all();

     return response()->json($academicos);
}
```

por:

```
public function index()
{
     $academicos = Academic::with('department')->get();

     return response()->json($academicos);
}
```